# CE 1.9 - Automatic Restock of Product by predetermined date

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, inventory, manage-stock

When we sell out of a product in magento its marked "out of stock". We then order the new stock and wait for it to arrive before manually setting the product back to "in stock". The trouble with this approach is it can often take weeks for the new stock to arrive and managing a large catalog of 10k+ products we often forget to put these products back "in stock".

We usually have a set date when we know when we will be receiving a restock delivery so if we could just put this date in to magento and have it restock on that date all our troubles would be over.

Is there a way to have magento automatically restock products on a predetermined date?